# Dirichlet Regression output and using the calculated coefficients in regression model

Tags: regression, modeling, dirichlet-distribution

I am very new to Dirichlet Regression and trying to make sense of the output and the regression coefficients. I am doing a biomass study and have tested the following variables (DBHH, DBH + H, DBH and DBH + Cr_L) in my models to determine the best model to describe the biomass proportions using Dirichlet Regression. According to the ANOVA test, model 3 was the best model with only one variable (DBH).

My question as follow:

(1) My understanding is that one can use the coefficients as one would in a linear regression model to calculate the proportions as in the predict (BM3) output, but when I calculate it, I don't get the same result as in the predict (BM3) table? For example, when we take the proportion of Needle mass for tree no (1) with DBH of 10.4. I have used the following formula (using the needle mass coefficients below) to calculate the proportion:

log(BM) = 1.826069-0.004529*10.4

log(BM) = 1.778967

EXP(1.778967) = 5.923734

The proportion of Needles for tree no 1 is 0.12628735 according to the predict(BM3) output and not 5.923734. What am I missing here? I would like to use a regression model to calculate the proportion of biomass components for the larger population for which I have DBH and estimated mass to compare the Dirichlet approach with the results of my models.

Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you making predictions by hand when the R module used will do this automatically? Run that code and see if it doesn't help you understand why using a single coefficient can be misleading. http://r-statistics.co/Dirichlet-Regression-With-R.html

Comment: Thanks Mike, guess it is for me to wrap my head around the mechanism of the predictions, also to be able to plug the formula into Excel for further calculations